# Jquery loginAlert is not defined

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to call a jquery function via php.

In my PHP Pages head section I have :

`<script src="login.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

this file contains:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function loginAlert() {
    alert ('Message when logging in');
}

});
```

Below this in the php pages head section I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
<?php if ($login === 1) { ?>
    loginAlert();
<?php }  ?>
});
</script>
```

When I load the page the chrome console shows:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: loginAlert is not defined ReferenceError: loginAlert is not defined

Uncaught ReferenceError: loginAlert is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong ?
How can I call this function ?

Comment: Define the **loginAlert** function outside ready function

Comment: Du you have the script tag included before or after you jquery inclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the Function outside of document.ready or You can use **Function expression**.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

      // Function expression
      var loginAlert = function() {
         alert ('Message when logging in');
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks that has helped.

Answer (score 0):

See below code may it helps !!

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $login = 1;
    if ($login === 1) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>$(document).ready(function() { loginAlert(); });</script>";
    }
?>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loginAlert() {
        alert ('Message when logging in');
    }
</script>
```

> Note : Do not forget to include jQuery CDN.

Answer (score 0):

Define your function outside `document.ready` as it is not accessible 
as

```
<script>
function loginAlert() {
    alert ('Message when logging in');
}
$(document).ready(function(){
});
</script>
```